# Complicated loop creation

Tags: r, loops, nested, sequence

I'm in need of desperate help, there is some data wrangling I do by hand in excel which is just painfully long and I'd like to make it more automated in R; I've got experience with R, but not enough to figure out on how to write this out. So here are the dataframe(s) in mind (click link wouldn't let me embed):

[image]

This is the start of it essentially, the source information is dataframe1. I'm essentially wanting to fill corresponding cells in dataframe2 with the relevant data result. So imagine these are just sequences found in each sample. The sequence has a modified version of itself [MOD] positioned specifically in it, and a non-modified version of itself (without the [MOD] in column 2). I essentially very very simply work out the modification percentage for each sample. So for sample 1, the first sequence 'ABCDEF', the % for [MOD1] is ((1)/(1+0.5+3))*100 = 22.22% etc which should go into the MOD1(%) row of dataframe2 for Sample_1 once calculated, then this is does for each sample across. Then I go down to the next sequence, again dividing the total value of the modified sequence (specific to position in the sequence and the modification itself, i.e. Mod 1 being based after G specifically) and repeat this.

What I need is a nested loop (I presume a nested loop I'm really unsure) that:

1. Searches column 1, gathers/highlights/isolates the rows that start matching, then stop when it reaches a difference (i.e. the new sequence on column 1 row 4)
2. Then it'll search column 2 for the the modified sequences, I'd imagine I'd have a list telling it that the modifications that exist are 'MOD1' and 'MOD2' etc. So it'll go to rows 1-3 (now they've been isolated), column 2 and find the first modification [MOD1].
3. Then it needs to gather the value of of the first sample (column 3) for this first isolated MOD1 of the first sequence, and do that calculation I mentioned above  and then create dataframe2, which will have the sequence of interest, the mod of interest (with which one it is) with the percentage result for the first sample of the first mod will be placed in there (dataframe2, column 3, row 1)
4. Then it needs to go search for the 2nd modification (if present) and repeat this, to fill the MOD2(%) for the first sample again in dataframe2
5. It needs to then repeat this for each sample across the dataframe1 to put this resulting info in dataframe2
6. Following that, it will then go onto its search of finding the next set of rows for a 'new sequence', isolate again and repeat.
   I deeply apologise for the complication of this (well complicated in my opinion, whomever is reading may not), I just would like to save hours as I have to do this with hundreds of sequences, so it would be extremely helpful to get this into a script. I've tried to make attempts at this, but I keep failing at the first step of conceptualizing what needs to be done function wise.

Please let me know if you need any further context or information.

EDIT:: Okay here is an example instead, and it's actually a bit more complicated than I wanted originally (or at least in my eyes)

```
df1 <- data.frame(sequence = c(rep("ABC", 3), rep("GHI", 2)),
                  mod = c("ABC[MOD1]", "ABC", "A[MOD1]B[MOD2]C", "G[MOD1]H[MOD1]I", "GHI"),
                  sample_1 = c(1, 0.5, 3, 3, 0.25),
                  sample_2 = c(1.5, 0.75, 2, 1.75, 0.5)) #This is the initial dataframe

df2 <- data.frame(sequence = c(rep("ABC", 3), rep("GHI", 2)),
                  mod = c("[3]MOD1","[1]MOD1","[2]MOD2", "[1]MOD1", "[2]MOD1"),
                  sample_1 = c(0.22,0.67,0.67,0.92,0.92),
                  sample_2 = c(0.35,0.47,0.47,0.78,0.78))
```

Essentially, the desired outcome will be the Modifications (MOD1 and MOD2) separately have the calculations done for them, even if they will result in the same value, I realise I still need to have that information down. Additionally, because there will be multiple modifications and potentially the same ones in the sequence, having the position of where it was i.e. ABC[MOD1] is position [3] with the type of Mod would be extremely useful.

Comment: Please provide your example data set in R code using `data.frame()` instead of a picture.

Comment: It would also be helpful to have the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to get what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

locate_mod_pos <- function(x) {
  str_locate_all(x, "\\[MOD.\\]") |> 
    map(~ .x |> 
          as_tibble() |> 
          mutate(loc = start - lag(end),
                 loc = if_else(is.na(loc), start - 1L, loc)) |> 
          pull(loc))
}

df1 |> 
  group_by(sequence) |> 
  mutate(across(c(sample_1, sample_2), ~ .x / sum(.x))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(mod_pos = locate_mod_pos(mod),
         mod = str_extract_all(mod, "\\[MOD.\\]")) |> 
  unnest(c(mod, mod_pos)) |> 
  mutate(mod = str_remove_all(mod, "\\[|\\]"),
         mod = paste0("[", mod_pos, "]", mod)) |> 
  select(-mod_pos)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  sequence mod     sample_1 sample_2
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ABC      [3]MOD1    0.222    0.353
2 ABC      [1]MOD1    0.667    0.471
3 ABC      [2]MOD2    0.667    0.471
4 GHI      [1]MOD1    0.923    0.778
5 GHI      [2]MOD1    0.923    0.778
```

However, this works with the test data you provided, but I'm not 100% certain it works if there are more than 2 instances of [MOD] appearing in a particular row of data, so please check if this works on your actual data if there are such cases.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! This works perfectly for what I described, however, I realised that the original dataframe and output requires a few additional features, I've put that context and the example/output dataframes in the edit. I apologise for not noting these in the original post, and I know it creates more complications. I see what you've done and how you've done it I believe.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide what the outcome would look like exactly, because evidently there's something I'm not understanding about the meaning of the digit in the square brackets.

Comment: Hello! Yes, the dataframe2 I put in the edit is certainly the exact desired outcome. The relevance of the number in the [] brackets is the position of the modification in the sequence. In what I'm looking at,  a sequence can have multiple modifications (MOD1 or MOD2) in it, in a different position of the sequence, and it can have the same modification in the sequence more than once. Even though the values are technically the same if that happens, they are positioned after a different letter which is important in what I'm doing I believe.

Comment: In that case, it's not clear to me at all why the values should uniformly be 0s, and I don't understand why you added the comment "the zeroes of course will be replaced with the calculated values" if the calculated values are in fact 0.

Comment: Apologies I see what you mean I forgot to edit that, it's now sorted, they are the calculated values now following what I described above